# Is it possible to render page with unsupported font symbols in webbrowser control in wp7 with some custom font

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, fonts, browser

I need to open pages in an unsupported language, for example in Georgian/Armenian. To do that I try to embed some unsupported font into the browser control and choose that font(Sylfaen in my case) as FontFamily in webbrowser control- browser still cant recognize it. Is there a way to render the webpage, using non standard font?
`FontFamily="/Fonts/bpg_glaho_sylfaen.ttf#Sylfaen"` and set copy to output of bpg_glaho_sylfaen.ttf font to "Copy If Newer".
[image]
example of such unsupported page: http://www.google.ge/xhtml?gwt=on&hl=ka&q=%E1%83%A2%E1%83%94%E1%83%A1%E1%83%A2

Comment: How are you embedding the font? Show your code. Don't just describe it.

Comment: @MattLacey added the code of "font embedding".

Comment: Font has georgian symbols. Tho if i open "georgian" google-it displays squares instead of letters.

Comment: oops..May be thats not CONTROL's fault, but website's?.. If website uses Arial for example- render will use arial too and system arial is trimmed, so i get squares..

Comment: Anyway i need to render the page with that characters visible. Thats why i wanted to use wb control and create a custom one that is not dependant on system fonts.

Comment: You've only shown part of how you're using the font. Where are you showing the HTML which consumes this?

Comment: @MattLacey just open it in webbrowser control: `wbControl.Navigate(new Uri("http://google.com"));`

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are trying to install a font that is not built in in Windows phone 7.

If this is the case, yet Microsoft doesn't support font installation in windows phone 7.
[similar question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/add-fonts-to-windows-phone-7/b0e016fe-1f10-4be4-9e5e-fea8a12fbd80)

Comment: Nope. I want to open pages that are written with glyphs, which are not supported by built in fonts. I thought about getting HTML of the page and changing BODY font to the one that is embedded in webbrowser, but font property seems to work in some its internal use only. And i want to rerender the page with embedded font and show it to user. I hoped that maybe there is alternative HTML parser or dont know...

Comment: have you unit tested you code, what if font coming from (.css file) and not in html.

Comment: @Saaboor Awan, the problem is in another thing, not in where the font is coming from. Its in browser renderer itself. It tries to use its internal system fonts to render pages. And if the characters are unknown for it- it shows squares. As i see there is no way for now to change this behavior ( Thank you for attention.